# How to programmatically collapse a p-fieldset in typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, primeng

I need to collapse a fieldset when another is opened.  I have tried setting the attribute and using a Boolean to change the state of the fieldset collapsed attribute but nothing seems to work.  Changing the Boolean value seems to work the first time but not onAfterToggle event

```
<p-fieldset [collapsed]="collapseCalendar" id="calendarFieldset" [toggleable]="true" (onAfterToggle)="fieldSetClicked($event)" >
```

```
fieldSetClicked(event){
var calendarFieldset = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("calendarFieldset");
var exportFieldset = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("exportFieldset");
var importFieldset = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("importFieldset");

if(event.originalEvent.target.innerText === "Customization" && event.collapsed === false){
  //close rest
  exportFieldset.setAttribute('collapsed', "true");
  importFieldset.setAttribute('collapsed', "true");
  this.collapseExport = true;
  this.collapseImport = true;
}
```

I have tried changing the attribute state and setting a boolean value for the collapsed tag

Answer (score 2):

If you only have these three `p-fieldset` inside your component your can do the following:
1- Read all FieldSet using `@ViewChildren` like that:

```
  @ViewChildren(Fieldset) fields: QueryList<Fieldset>;
```

3- Declear an object of key value, key is an id of filedSet and the value represents the collapse state

```
  collapsedState: { [id: string]: boolean } = {};
```

2- implement `AfterViewInit` in your component and inside `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
  this.fields.forEach((field) => {
      this.collapsedState[field.id] = field.collapsed;
    });
```

**The above function will iterate over the fields and add the initial state**

inside your template:

1- Add a unique template reference for each `p-filedSet` component and `(onAfterToggle)=yourFunction(templateRef)`,collapsed property will change according to the object of `collapsedState`  like that:

```
<p-fieldset
  legend="Header"
  #dd
  [collapsed]="collapsedState[dd.id] ?? false"
  [toggleable]="true"
  (onAfterToggle)="collapseOther(dd)"
>
```

Implementation of `collapseOther` function:

```
  collapseOther(toggledField: Fieldset) {
    if (toggledField.collapsed) {
      return;
    }
    //take other not toggled elements
    const otherEls = this.fields.filter((el) => el.id != toggledField.id);
    
    for (let filedId of Object.keys(this.collapsedState)) {
      const fieldSetCollapsed = otherEls.some((el) => el.id == filedId)
        ? true
        : false;
      this.collapsedState[filedId] = fieldSetCollapsed;
    }
  }
}
```

> It's a workaround but it works for me.

Comment: Thank you for this, it helped with one use case.  Is there anything that could be done for dynamically created fieldsets?

Comment: You're welcome, can you share a `Stackblitz` link for your use case, I'm ready to help you @jason316